# Display of last 10 visited pages from different Apps

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, android-activity

I have nearly 20+ pages from different Web application that a user can access once he login. I have this 'Recent Activity' section on my Home page where I have to show the last 10 visited pages by the user ( if possible along with date and time of visiting). The pages are jsp pages. I dont know how I can acheive this basically I am more a frontend developer so can I do this with jquery, jsp, js etc.. or anyother technoloiges. We use Java technology also. Please let me know any sample code or way of approach to do it.
Thanks

Comment: If all of the different web applications are on the same domain, you could probably use history, session, local storage or cookies, otherwise keeping track of it server-side would make more sense.

Comment: Yes, all the applications are on the same domain. I will try to figure it out using the options which you mentioned. Please let me know if you have some examples to share

Answer (score 0):

I am a php developer, not too familiar with jsp, but i am sure it would be the same logic.

You have 2 option here:

Option 1:
Create a database table and record all the user flow whenever the user access an application.

Option 2:

Save all the flow in a cookie variable so whenever the user logs in  you can pull out all his info from the cookie variable.

Personally i rather use the option 1, because if the use clears out the cookie/session variable you will lose lo all the information.

Since i am not a jsp i can't providew with a sample code. Hope this get your started at least.

Answer (score 0):

This information may be stored on Cookies or User Session.

If it's available on cookies, you can access and manipulate it using JavaScript or any other server-side languages.

Do you want some example on how to use it using JSP&Servlets?

There's pros and cons for each approach.

Cookies: User can cleanup private browser data, and cookies go away with it.

Sessions: You can store it in some database or log file, for future load or/and analysis.

Cons is the management of this data in any layer. But it's not a big problem.

Comment: Yes, Please provide me some examples. Also, looking on interent I came to know that HTML5 has this local-storage more like a cookie but it will stay even the user do cleanup. This is just a thought to share not sure how it works.